# angularjs throws Error: [ng:areq] in resolving the lazyloading the scripts and adding a view controller separately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I don't know why this first state works but the second one doesn't:

**Working state:**

```
.state('app.pages.invoice', {
        url: '/invoice',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/pages_invoice.html",
        title: 'Invoice',
        resolve: {
            "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                return Auth.$requireSignIn();
            }]
        }

    })
```

**Not working state, throwing the `Error: [ng:areq]`:**

> validationCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

```
.state('app.form.validation', {

        controller: "validationCtrl",

        url: '/validation',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/form_validation.html",
        title: 'Form Validate',

        resolve: {
            "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                return Auth.$requireSignIn();
            }]
        }


    })
```

This second one works only when the controller is injected via this:

```
resolve: loadSequence('validationCtrl')
```

**that is (controller is moved into the resolve and there is not currentAuth anymore):**

```
.state('app.form.validation', {

        url: '/validation',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/form_validation.html",
        title: 'Form Validate',

        resolve: loadSequence('validationCtrl')
    })
```

and then I don't know how to integrate my `currentAuth` element into the resolve again. 
How can I inject the  **validationCtrl.js** via resolve and add the **currentAuth** element also into **resolve**?

**here is the loadsequence function:**

```
// Generates a resolve object previously configured in constant.JS_REQUIRES (config.constant.js)
function loadSequence() {
    var _args = arguments;
    return {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
        function ($ocLL, $q) {
            var promise = $q.when(1);
            for (var i = 0, len = _args.length; i < len; i++) {
                promise = promiseThen(_args[i]);
            }
            return promise;

            function promiseThen(_arg) {
                if (typeof _arg == 'function')
                    return promise.then(_arg);
                else
                    return promise.then(function () {
                        var nowLoad = requiredData(_arg);
                        if (!nowLoad)
                            return $.error('Route resolve: Bad resource name [' + _arg + ']');
                        return $ocLL.load(nowLoad);
                    });
            }

            function requiredData(name) {
                if (jsRequires.modules)
                    for (var m in jsRequires.modules)
                        if (jsRequires.modules[m].name && jsRequires.modules[m].name === name)
                            return jsRequires.modules[m];
                return jsRequires.scripts && jsRequires.scripts[name];
            }
        }]
    };
}
```

My first state doesn't have any controller, so I am fine resolving the **currentAuth** alone. But when the view has a controller, add the **currentAuth** causes the controller not to work anymore.

### note:

my currentAuth is taken from [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#user-content-authenticating-with-routers).

### update:

herer is the  **validationCtrl.js**:

```
    app.controller('ValidationCtrl', ["$scope", "$state", "$timeout", "SweetAlert", "$location",
        function ($scope, $state, $timeout, SweetAlert, $location) {
...
```

### update 2:

basically the question is to allow only currently signed in users to view the pages which are children of `app.`; so my parent view is like this: so basically I am looking to inject the currentAuth factory into the main parent view and the children should inherit this. They cannot be viewed unless the currentAuth in the parent is resolved.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
    resolve: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'angularMoment', 'uiSwitch', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster', 'ngAside', 'vAccordion', 'sweet-alert', 'chartjs', 'tc.chartjs', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'chatCtrl'),
    abstract: true
})
```

### edit 1:

I have put the question in other words as [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061833/angularjs-multiple-resolve-with-loadsequence-and-auth-permission) here and trying to find an answer to multiple resolve states.

### edit 2:

here is the main.js: [pastebin url](http://pastebin.com/M1m4kM8d)

and the validationCtrl.js [pastebin url](http://pastebin.com/bfs5LdpF).
actually, the validationCtrl is just an example controller among other controllers I have. 
Question is how to block view permission for child views unless the parent currentAuth is resolved? given that I don't know how to handle multiple resolve with loadsequence and a singleton factory.

Comment: Did you define CurrentAuth in your controller? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj as the documentation https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#user-content-authenticating-with-routers says, i just need to throw it in the controller and function, that is all, right?

Comment: can i see your full validationCtrl.js and your mainapp.js file?

Comment: @pritishvaidya I added an update with the pastebin links.

Comment: thanks i'll try my best :)

Comment: the only problem seems to be the lower case v in validationCtrl.

Comment: By the way, resolves are inherited form parent states, no need to c/c it everywhere : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies. Finnaly you can pass multiple object to resolve like this : {'myController':loadSequence('validationController', "currentAuth":...}. It doesn't work ?

Comment: @Walfrat could you please write up an answer to see what you exactly propose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using **ui router** as a routing framework for your SPA app.

**Error: [ng:areq]**

the error you get:

> validationCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

is due to the declaration of the controller within the state, the name of the controller function is not resolved because "ValidationCtrl" is not equal to "validationCtrl" then correct state is:

```
.state('app.form.validation', {

    controller: "ValidationCtrl",

    url: '/validation',
    templateUrl: "assets/views/form_validation.html",
    title: 'Form Validate',

    resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
            return Auth.$requireSignIn();
        }]
    }


})
```

**Abstract States - Nested States**

to answer the second question, a useful example for your case may be this:

```
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
    resolve: { 
    scripts: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'angularMoment', 'uiSwitch', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster', 'ngAside', 'vAccordion', 'sweet-alert', 'chartjs', 'tc.chartjs', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'chatCtrl').deps,
    currentAuth: function(Auth){ return Auth.$requireSignIn();}
    },
    abstract: true
})
.state('app.pages.invoice', {
        // url will become '/app/invoice'
        url: '/invoice',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/pages_invoice.html",
        title: 'Invoice'
        

    })
    .state('app.form.validation', {

        controller: "ValidationCtrl",
        // url will become '/app/validation'
        url: '/validation',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/form_validation.html",
        title: 'Form Validate'


    })
```

As you can see from the example in the resolve of the abstract state you can define different factory functions, ui router will wait until all dependencies are resolved before resolving the children states.

Resolve property explanation :

> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:
>
> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
>
> factory - {string|function}:
> If string, then it is an alias for a service.
> Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

for more details I refer you to [ui router doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views).

Comment: I get this error when I implement the second question nested solution's answer: http://pastebin.com/cGTztz4k
i think because my other state also have resolve parameter which loads the controllers and scripts.

Comment: actually this should work, but the loadsequence function inside the resolve throws an error.

Comment: check my last edit. I assuming you can resolve loadSequence function in your app.config.

Comment: here is another error this time: `angular.js:11655 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object`

Comment: Ok,I noticed only now that the entire loadSequence function is in 'deps'... check the last edit.

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment i suggest you to try the following :

```
.state('app.form.validation', {

        url: '/validation',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/form_validation.html",
        title: 'Form Validate',
        controller: "validationCtrl",
        resolve:{
            "myCtrl": loadSequence('validationCtrl'),
             "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                return Auth.$requireSignIn();
             }]
        }
    })
```

The other part of my comment was about the fact that [child states inherits parent's resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies) and children can override it.

So you can just do the following :

```
.state('app', {
        // all states require logging by default
        resolve:{
             "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                return Auth.$requireSignIn();
                // i'm guessing we're redirecting toward app.login if not logged
             }]
        }
    })
    .state('app.login', {
        resolve:{
          "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                return true;// just be sure to not do infinite redirections
             }]
        }
    })
```

Note if you have some trouble because Auth isn't yet loaded with lazy loading, you should be able to load it in a `angular.run`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly coming to the error

> Error: [ng:areq]:
>    validationCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

```
controller: "validationCtrl", change it according to the main controller
that is
```

This means there is no validationCtrl function.

I may be wrong but i think there is  a small typo' in this line in your controller `controller: "validationCtrl"`, change it according to the `**main controller**` `controller: "ValidationCtrl"`
    that is

This error happens due to either defining two `angular.modules` with the same name in different files containing different arguments as you may be trying to implement the `dependancy` injection.

It causes the problem as the script loaded inyour main html file won't know which angular.module to be configured.

To resolve this define the angular.modules with different names.

> How to block view permission for child views unless the parent currentAuth is resolved

You can install this package [angular middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-middleware)This `middleware` package contains  some `pre-defined`  route functions or you can also create your own functions.Along with this $[http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation using the success and callback functions,you can create your own `middleware` and the `auth` service while using a `singleton` factory

**OR**

Assuming that you are using `node.js` as your `backend` you can use `[middleware][3]` routing in your server using **[express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)** and map it to the frontend routes.

[Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/route-middleware-to-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-node-js) is a perfect tutorial for middleware authentication in nodejs

Comment: this is not the answer i am looking for. I already had passport but I am not using it anymore. I just want to manage the view using the firebase auth management. But since my views are parent/child, and each state has already a resolve that works with a loadsequence, I don't know how to bring in the firebase auth check into this chain.

Comment: so basically you just want user to be auth and then route to the particular routes and not to the others?